# Git pulling / merging from a specific and branch

Tags: git, github, merge

I am working on open-source project on github, and I cloned a the project by doing

`git clone git@gitlab.domain.com:project.git`

Now, All works fine, I can run the project and working on it. But this was a master branch, and now
someone has created a branch called `user_interface` and added some basic HTML, now I need to pull this `user_interface` and merge it to my local working file, so I can immediately start using these additional features from that user. But, the problem is specifying how to explicitly call call that branch `user_interface` and merge it to my local copy.

So far, I tried only `git pull`, but it pulls the original data and merges it to my local directory, so I end up with the same copy I got the last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `git pull` your repository is already aware of the new branch on the "main" repository.

Now you need to make the remote branch a local branch. You can achieve this with:

`$ git checkout user_interface`

Then go back to master:

`$ git checkout master`

and merge:

`$ git merge user_interface`

Comment: Thanks, I did all you the steps, it showed me some files with green++ and red -- in them, so does this literally mean, now that I am using all files and updated committed to `user_interface`?

Comment: Yes, you are in master branch with the modifications of `user_interface` merged into it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I want to push this repo, but didn't want it to merge with the `master` or the `user_interface` branches, but to its own specific branch, how do I give it a new branch name and push that branch ?

Comment: Have you already committed into your local copy of `master` or not? If you haven't committed anything yet, check out a new branch `git checkout -b ui_and_my_changes` (you can call it whatever makes sense). Then commit any changes you've made onto that new branch and `git merge user_interface` to bring in the other branch. The only thing left is to handle any merge conflicts that might have popped up.

Comment: Even if on the local master has commited changes, you can push the only the `ui_and_my_changes` with `$ git push origin ui_and_my_changes`. This won't "disturb" origin's master.

Answer (score 1):

With `git fetch` you'll grab any branches in the remote repository and can then do whatever you want.

Comment: The problem is that there's no tracking branch for the new remote branch `user_interface`.

Comment: You don't need a local branch for merging, you can `git merge origin/user_interface` to the currently checked out branch.

Answer (score 1):

If i correct undertund You,  shoud use

git pull origin user_interface

and if you want to get those changes on user_interface branch you need to **fetch** repository to show remote branches and checkout to it and **marge** within previously marget by **git pull origin user_interface** master

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to fetch a copy of the entire git repository from the remote server (just in case it's been updated since you last pulled):

```
git fetch origin
```

Then you'll need to checkout that branch and link it to the remote branch:

```
git checkout -b user_interface origin/user_interface
```

You'll now be on the user_interface branch locally, along with having it track the remote branch (so you can run a simple `git pull` command). To merge it in to your master, switch back to master and merge it in:

```
git checkout master
git merge user_interface
```

That's it!

Comment: thanks, do you know the solution for this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772414/git-pulling-merging-from-a-specific-and-branch#comment27676964_18772774